# как работать с большими данными в командной строке

Tags: ubuntu, строки, bash, cmd

использую командную строку в ubuntu для выполнения команд, вываливается ошибка agrument list too long, какие есть варианты решения проблемы? увеличить лимит?(как это сделать?) записывать в файл данные? какие еще есть способы? что посоветуете?

любой ответ будет оценен

Comment: Нужно больше конкретики, а лучше расскажите задачу которую вы решаете. Обычно подобные проблемы решают при помощи find

Comment: @AlexeyTen `./script.sh -args {большой список аргументов}`

Comment: И откуда взялся этот «большой список»?

Comment: Идея передавать бинарные данные большого размера в виде аргумента командной строки видится мне довольно спорной. Файлы, пайты, сокеты и наверняка ешё чего-ниубдь есть более подходящее для этой задачи

Comment: передавайте большие аргументы через STDIN