# Как передать скрипту аргументы из файла?

Tags: python, bash, stdin

```
python3 /home/user/script.py -arg | < cat /home/user/filename.txt
```

Нет такого файла.

```
cat /home/user/filename.txt
```

Так всё работает.

Comment: попробуйте `python3 /home/user/script.py -arg  $(cat /home/user/filename.txt)`

Comment: Но так получится тоже самое что и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1544546/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так попробуйте

```
python3 /home/user/script.py < /home/user/filename.txt
```

Только убедитесь что пути указаны верно и имеются права доступа к файлу с аргументами